# What is the math behind CSS’s background-size: contain

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to dynamically get the current size of the background image, not the natural size, the size that it changes to when the window is resized or the screen is a different size.
I am using

```
html {
  background: url("./bg.png");
  background-size: contain;
}
```

I know I can get the window size by using `window.innerHeight` and `window.innerWidth`

I am looking for a way to get the size the background image gets resized to using the natural size and the window size.

Comment: the duplicate is finding the scale but it would be easy to find the sizes the same way (by applying the scale to the intial sizes)